# Referencing static files with composite URLs in SproutCore

Tags: sproutcore, sproutcore-2

I’m using `static_url` to refer to static files that are located in the *resources* directory. This works fine when for literal URL strings but it doesn’t work for composite URLs that were constructed using variables:

```
static_url(foo + '/' + bar)
```

This is just ignored by SproutCore’s pre-processor.

So is there some way to refer to a static file with a composite URL? Or, since I’m working with a finite set of URLs, do I have to introduce each composite URL before I can refer to it?

Answer (score 1):

This answers assumes that you are using SC1.

I believe that `static_url()` is processed by the build tools (sc-build and sc-server) at compile time and not the framework at runtime.

The code for the build tools can be found at https://github.com/sproutcore/abbot.  I believe `base.rb replace_static_url()` is where the work gets done.

So the following code:

```
imageView: SC.ImageView.design({
  layout: { top: 0, left: 0, width: 200, height: 18 },
  value: static_url('picture.png')
})
```

gets compiled into the following before being delivered to the browser:

```
imageView: SC.ImageView.design({
  layout: { top: 0, left: 0, width: 200, height: 18 },
  value: '/static/vvv/en/current/source/resources/picture.png?1320555999'
})
```

To create composite URL at runtime, try using bindings.

```
// In your view
imageView: SC.ImageView.design({
  layout: { top: 0, left: 0, width: 200, height: 18 },
  valueBinding: 'Vvv.controller.imageValue'
}) 

// In another file, define the controller
Vvv.controller = SC.Object.create({
    foo: '/static/vvv/en/current/source/resources',
    bar: 'bug.png',

    imageValue: function() {
       return this.get('foo') + '/' + this.get('bar');
    }.property().cacheable()
});
```

Also, if you have a finite set of resources, you may want to give this a go:

```
Vvv.controller = SC.Object.create({
    foo: static_url('foo.png'),
    bar: static_url('bar.png'),
    isFoo: false,

    imageValue: function() {
       if (this.get('isFoo')) {
           return this.get('foo');
       } else {
           return this.get('bar');
       }
    }.property('isFoo').cacheable()
});
```

You can change the image at runtime by setting `isFoo` to true or false.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already know that `static_url` is just some kind of hint for the builder to replace it by the static URL that corresponds to its argument. The point is that I try to request static resources depending on parameters but I want to avoid to introduce each to SproutCore. I’d rather just try to request them and use a fallback if one does not exist.